# Insert Into SQL Statement error 3346

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am trying to INSERT INTO a table in SQL but for some reason it says the number of query values and destination fields are not the same and I'm not sure why it is saying that.  I have researched the error (3346) with no luck for a fix.  I am rather new to VBA so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
"INSERT INTO Clients (Col1, Col2, Col3)" & _
        "SELECT DISTINCT DD.[Client ID] " & _
        "FROM " & tableName & " as DD " & _
        "Where CL.[Client ID] NOT IN (SELECT DD.[Client ID] FROM " & tableName & " as DD)"
```

Comment: You are trying to insert 3 columns -- col1, col2, and col3.  However, you are only selecting 1, client id...  The number of columns in your insert statement must match that in your select statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to insert into 3 columns from one column it's confused
this will work:

```
"INSERT INTO Clients (Col1)" & _
    "SELECT DISTINCT DD.[Client ID] " & _
    "FROM " & tableName & " as DD " & _
    "Where DD.[Client ID] NOT IN (SELECT DD.[Client ID] FROM " & tableName & " as DD)"
```

but it does not insert any row because there is no result for select statement.
Think a little more on it and decide exactly what do you want to insert into where?